# HttpWebResponse is returned as null though the Service is returning some data

Tags: wcf, rest

My WCF REST Service is returning List of Data Contracts. When I try to read the response, i'm getting null and I noticed the below error at the highlighted in Bold code.
"Length = 'requestStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'"

```
        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            if (httpMethod.ToUpper() == Constants.WEBHTTPGET)
            {
                if (request != null && request.ToString().Length > 0)
                    url += string.Format("/{0}", request.ToString());
            }

            // Create HttpWebRequest object 
            HttpWebRequest WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            WebRequest.Method = httpMethod;
            WebRequest.ContentType = @"application/xml; charset=utf-8";

            if (IsTimeoutIncrementRequired(url))
                WebRequest.Timeout = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebRequestTimeout"] != null) ? (Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebRequestTimeout"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) : Constants.WebRequestTimeout; 

            // Add HTTP headers 
            WebRequest.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R"));
            WebRequest.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2009-09-19");


            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] != null)
            {
                DataContract.User userObj = (DataContract.User)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"];
                //Set Header content type and Authetincation
                WebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetAuthHeader(userObj.UserName, userObj.Password));
                CultureInfo culture = ResolveCulture();
                if (culture != null && culture.Name != null)
                {
                    WebRequest.Headers.Add("ClientBrowserCulture", culture.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    WebRequest.Headers.Add("ClientBrowserCulture", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DISCurrentCulture"]);
                }

            }
            if (httpMethod.ToUpper() == Constants.WEBHTTPPOST)
            {
                string xmlString = ObjectToXml(request);
                WebRequest.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(xmlString);
                **using (Stream stream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(xmlString));
                }**
            }
            else
            {
                WebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            }

            resp = WebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;


        }
```

Comment: Please provide me some solution for this issue

Comment: I noticed the below exception also :System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---